# Partial key match in a sorted List<string>

Tags: .net, algorithm, optimization, search

Say I have a sorted list of strings like `{"a1", "a2", "b0", "b2", "c1", ...}` and want to determine an index of the first element starting from "b". What is the fastest way to get it in .NET 4? Memory is not a problem.

Comment: Do you mean you want the index of the first element that has "b" as the first character?  (i.e. 2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457160/the-most-efficient-algorithm-to-find-first-prefix-match-from-a-sorted-string-arra)

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
var list = new List<string> { "a1", "a2", "b0", "b2", "c1" };
int index = list.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith("b"));
```

If your list is huge and performance is an issue, than consider the answer in the possible duplicate as noted by Joel Rondeau in his comment to your question.

Comment: This is awesome! I used `List<T>` for three years and didn't know about this method.

Answer (score 0):

If for "fastest" you mean "easiest to implement" then

Something roughly like this:

```
static int FirstIndex(this IEnumerable<T> coll, Predicate<T> pred)
{
    var it = coll.GetEnumerator();

    int index = 0;

    while(it.MoveNext())
    {
        if(pred(it.Current))
        {
           return index;
        }
        index++;
    }

     throw new ObjectNotFoundException();
}    

{"a1", "a2", "b0", "b2", "c1"}.FirstIndex(s => s.StartsWith("b"));
```

Or using the [Seq module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353685.aspx) from F# (caveat, I've never tried using these from C#... this syntax is probably wrong.):

```
Seq.findIndex(s => s.StartsWith("b"))(strings);
```